# Selecting part of a matrix in Octave to form another matrix

Tags: octave

Suppose I have the matrix

```matlab
a = [1 2 3;
      4 5 6; 
      7 8 9;]
```

I want to select the first two columns to form a matrix

```matlab
b = [1 2; 
      4 5; 
      7 8;]
```

How to achieve this in Octave?
I know how to select a single column, but how to select many columns (let's say, the first 8 columns of a matrix having 16 columns) and form a matrix with them?

Also, how to select rows in a similar manner to form a matrix?

Comment: While `a(:, linspace(9, 16, 8)) = [];` produces the desired result, it deletes columns from the original matrix. I want the original matrix to remain same and create a duplicate matrix having a subset of the columns

Comment: I recommend learning about the range operator ( : ) using the octave help/documentation. 
https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Ranges.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
b = a(:,1:2)
```

where `:` means taking all rows, and `1:2` means taking columns from 1 to 2.

Comment: Is there a way to make the slice open ended? My Pythonic intuition wants to write something like `a(:,1:)` to indicate columns 1 to end of columns, but this does not compile.

Comment: For anyone who had the same question I had: `a(:,2:end)` would be the syntax for an open-ended column slice for columns 2 onward!